# Set operation symbol problem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm asked to look for this **/A/** symbol in set operations but I can't find it.
Does anybody know what is this and how to use it?
Can you guys also cite some examples? Please help me.. Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: $\forall$ maybe?

Comment: Or possibly $|A|$?

Comment: Is it $/A/$ or $|A|$ ?

Comment: It is not also clear to me. 
Are |A| and /A/ both on set operations?

Comment: Havnt heard of $/A/$, but the first one is in set theory.

Comment: Tell me is it former or later!

Comment: If you still haven't see this /A/, then maybe this |A| is the right one. :) Maybe I just misunderstood the professor's drawing. LOL :D

Comment: Right, there is no $/A/$,it'll be $|A|$ see my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symbol $|A|$ represents the modulus or cardinality of set $A$. The cardinality of a set is a measure of the "number of elements of the set". For example, the set $A $= {7, 2, 16} contains 3 elements, and therefore A has a cardinality of 3. There are two approaches to cardinality – one which compares sets directly using bijections and injections, and another which uses cardinal numbers.The cardinality of a set is also called its size, when no confusion with other notions of size is possible.

The cardinality of a set A is usually denoted $| A |$, with a vertical bar on each side; this is the same notation as absolute value and the meaning depends on context. Alternatively, the cardinality of a set A may be denoted by $n(A)$ or $card(A)$, or #$A$.

Comment: I'm starting to get it. Can you elaborate it a little more? My brain is slower right now since I'm already tired.

Comment: The representation denotes the total no. of elements present in the set!

Comment: Already accepted. :)
So... If there is A={7,2,16} the answer is 3? Please forgive my slowness

Comment: @SagnikSaha what a douchebag..